Local Images are not visible on Android debug build in react-native
Images are not visible on Android debug build, but it is visible on release build and ios build too.
Images are visible when I am using urls but when I am trying to use local images it's not visible for Android.

  <Image source={require('./png/headershape.png')}/>

the .png image is on same level of .tsx file
Can someone know what can be the reason for this.

local images as in images placed in native folders? or images which are in your local (locahost) system?

@Kartikey,the image is on same level of .tsx file
